# Minecraft server on CreeperHost with online-mode set to false

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm testing something, and I am about to buy server hosting on CreeperHost.
Will my Minecraft server work on CreeperHost with online-mode set to false in server.properties?
What does online mode actually do?

Comment: If you don't know what it does, why do you want to change it from the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creeperhost does not support but won't block offline mode servers, according to [their promo post at MC Ports Central](http://www.mcportcentral.co.za/index.php?topic=447.0):

> Also keep in mind, we won't block use of offline servers, however we are not willing to provide technical support towards them.

So offline mode will work on Creeperhost, but you're on your own if you need setup help or if anything goes wrong.

Running an offline mode server means that anyone can join with any name they want, even a server op's name (and therefore all their stuff and powers), since the server does not check with Mojang that they own that account name. A public offline mode server requires you to install and manage some other kind of authentication or access control in order to prevent that kind of abuse.

Answer (score 0):

With online mode disabled, the server will not make an attempt to validate a Minecraft account, meaning people with cracked accounts can join, and regular accounts can join when Mojang's servers are down. As for whether creeperhost allows online mode, I would say it's up to the server operator to change this in the config.

Comment: actually you don't even need an account you just need to set the username in the client to whatever you want and it'll be accepted